# Jquery set date to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have **start_date** datepicker and after some calculation result shown on **date_result** textfield and its working fine, here is code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('start_date, #week_number, #year_number, #month_number').change(function() {
        var yr = $('#year_number').val() * 365;
        var wk = $('#week_number').val() * 7;
        var days = yr + wk;
        var endDate = new Date($('#start_date').val());
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + Number(days));
        $('#date_result').val(endDate.getFullYear() + '-' + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + endDate.getDate());
    });
});
```

Here is: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8epztLv2/7/)

**Problem:** The date_result input value is empty, how can I set this value with calculated date?

```
<input type="text" value="" size="20" name="form[date_result]" id="date_result">
```

Comment: Check for errors in the console.

Comment: Also add the related HTML and if possible, a JSFiddle.

Comment: there is no error in console, here if [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8epztLv2/6/)

Comment: which browser do you use ?

Comment: @allogos "**The date_result input value is empty**" when is this happening. Are you talking about pageload?

Comment: Working on Chrome here. The input is fufilled with the date.

Comment: @Rajesh on pageload is like `<input type="text" value="" size="20" name="form[date_result]" id="date_result">` ,i want after selecting the date and calculation the code becomes like `<input type="text" value="2016-06-01" size="20" name="form[date_result]" id="date_result">`

Comment: Can you have a onLoad function and update value from there? [Sample  fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8epztLv2/8/)

Comment: @Rajesh Tried but not worked.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is then, coz its working on fiddle I shared.

Answer (score 0):

Adding months in Javascript generally may not always work as expected as some scenarios and edge-cases can lead to unexpected results.

For instance, the [`setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) function accepts only month values between 0-11 and also accepts a day parameter and can do some funny things when values outside of this range are used :

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range,
>   `setMonth()` attempts to update the date information in the `Date` object
>   accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for `monthValue`, the year will
>   be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.

**Consider using a Date-specific Library**

My recommendation would be to consider using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), which are specifically designed for handling this type of behavior and will likely make your code much easier to read :

```
$('#start_date, #month_number').change(function() {
   var months = $('#month_number').val();
   // Get your date as a moment (specifying the format you want to parse in)
   var end = moment($('#start_date').val(),"YYYY-MM-DD");
   // Add your months
   end.add(Number(months),'months');
   // You can even ease formatting (along with output format)
   $('#end_date').val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="date" id="start_date">
  <select id="month_number">
    <option value="0">Number of months to add</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="end_date" placeholder="End Date">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#start_date, #month_number').change(function() {
        var months = $('#month_number').val();
        // Get your date as a moment
        var end = moment($('#start_date').val(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
        // Add your months
        end.add(Number(months), 'months');
        // You can even ease formatting
        $('#end_date').val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8epztLv2/7/)  remove the name attribute and try once

Please Open the developer console to view the log

```
<input type="text" value="" size="20" id="date_result" placeholder="End Date">
```

Comment: Which browser you are working with. Please click the 'RUN' after you made any changes in jsfiddle. and put this code segement console.log($('#date_result').val());
you can see the log.